# Why does clip-path inset(0 0 0 0) produce a different result than not setting clip path?

Tags: css

I'm creating an animation where a div rolls upward from a clip-path of inset(100% 0 0 0) to inset(0 0 0 0). However, there is a small gap that appears between the bottom of the div and the parent container. The parent's position is relative and the child's height is 100%. If I look at the developer's tools and check the height of the child and parent, they both match.

Where is the gap coming from?

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#main {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 64vh;
  width: 38vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 10%;
  position: relative;
  border: 1vh solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#left-col {
  float: left;
  width: 4%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 46%;
  background: black;
}
#right-col {
  float: left;
  width: 4%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-left: 0;
  -webkit-clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0);
  clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0);
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section id='main'>
    <div id='left-col'></div>
    <div id='right-col'></div>
    <section>
</body>
```

If you'd like a visualization, check my Codepen: 
http://codepen.io/sentedelviento/pen/NRGbya

The left-col does not have a gap, and seems to be positioned the same as the right-col, except its clip-path isn't set. This unwanted behavior continues when I switch and set the clip-path to the left column. There is again a gap. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't tell you why, but it looks like a webkit bug with `-webkit-clip-path` and as far as I can see only happens in Chrome (I've tested it on Firefox, IE, Opera, and Chrome).

Try replacing the webkit `-webkit-clip-path: inset(0% 0% 0% 0%);` with `-webkit-clip-path: rect(0% 0% 0% 0%);`

or for: `-webkit-mask-clip`

or even just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

It is a rounding error of `clip-path`. Try to change the width of your codepen view and you will see.

I made a screencast to show: http://somup.com/cDQroDC3h